# Insert method - activation and deactivation on German Keyboards

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, german

Dear Stack Exchange community,

I have a German keyboard on my laptop since I bought my laptop in Germany, it has Windows 10 on it and the its name is "hp envy laptop 17-cg1xxx". I find the german layout very handy for almost everything, except when it comes to the insert mode.

I have no idea how it activates. I press some sequence of keys and it happens. I have no idea either how I turn it on or how I turn it off.

I did some research and the insert key should be called "einfg" on german keyboards... "einfg" is written on the "0" on the Numpad. I tried so hard but went not so far. Would anyone be so kind to tell me how I do activate the insert mode and how I deactivate it on this keyboard?

Answer (score 2):

First, "einfg" is correctly the translation for the "insert" action. To use "insert" instead of the number zero, you need to deactivate the Num lock. Depending on the settings, you will either have to press it twice (while num lock is deactivated) to switch between "insert" and "replace" (as on any standard keyboard), or you will have to press shift and the "ins" keys together to toggle between "insert" and "replace" (while num lock switched off).

Activating the Num lock will activate the number zero again.